# How do I keep position: relative content from overlapping my position: sticky header?

Tags: html, css, css-position, overlapping

I have a sticky top navbar that I want to stay visible and above all other content when scrolling. I have content on the page that I have set to `position: relative` so that I can position other elements around it. When I do this, the relative content ignores the navbar when scrolling and overlaps it. Is there any way for my to have my page content positioned relative and still have it observe the sticky navbar?

I've tried giving the relative content a top margin equal to the height of the navbar.

```css
.nav-bar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: solid rgb(179, 173, 173) 1px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.nav-bar #title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.test-class #test-content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(70, 67, 67);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <p id="title">Title</p>
</div>
<div class="test-class">
  <p id="test-content"></p>
</div>
```

Expected: sticky header stays above all other content.

Actual: Content overlaps header when its position is set to relative.

Comment: Nothing is set to `position: relative` in your code.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you describe, and use the [live demo feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: please update your snippet so it reproduces your issue

Comment: [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) is your friend.

Answer (score 11):

If you want your navbar stay always visible just give it a z-index bigger than your content

```
.nav-bar{
    position:sticky;
    top:0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom:solid rgb(179, 173, 173) 1px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    z-index: 1
}
```

Comment: why z-index? it will mess up layers

Comment: The sadest solution everybody wanted to avoid... :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Remove `position:absolute` from `.test-class #test-content` class. It works fine as you want.

```css
.nav-bar{
    position:sticky;
    top:0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom:solid rgb(179, 173, 173) 1px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.nav-bar #title{
    margin:0;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left: 2%;
}

.test-class #test-content {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:rgb(70, 67, 67);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <p id="title">Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="test-class">
        <p id="test-content"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .nav-bar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333333;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .nav-bar #title {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .test-class {
        padding: 16px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        height: 1500px;
    }
    .test-class #test-content {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: rgb(70, 67, 67);
        margin: 0;
    }
```